# Can I change the OOTB Sharepoint designer workflow Current Task: Assigned To?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I would like to use the OOTB Approval workflow, but I want the workflow to get the value for the Current Task: Assigned To from a Form Library.  Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you want to get the value for the “Assigned To” field in the picture below from a form library. If so, we cannot.
[image]

Then you could consider creating the approval workflow in SharePoint designer. And you could select the users from the form library.
[image]